# In C#.net Adding Button Control from code behind, that is not appearing on page when it loads in browser

Tags: c#, aspbutton

I am adding Asp:Button Controls in C# code behind. But when page loads in Browser, button doesn't appear on page. Here is my piece of code

```
    html.Append("<table>");
    html.Append("<tr><th>Student Name</th><th>Operations</th>");

    while (msdr.Read())
    {
        html.Append("<tr>");
        html.Append("<td>" + msdr[0] + "</td>");
        html.Append("<td align='center'><asp:Button ID='btnAdd' runat='server' OnClick='BtnAddStd_Click' Text='Add' /></td>");
        html.Append("</tr>");
     }
      html.Append("</table>");
      Placeholder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only append html inputs as buttons dynamically. ASP.Net components compile and get translated to html. The browser doesn't understand this part of your code:

`<asp:Button ID='btnAdd' runat='server' OnClick='BtnAddStd_Click' Text='Add' />`